# Copy files and folders older than x days using batch script

Tags: batch-file

**my batch script**

```
set "Sourcefolder=D:\PurgeScriptExecute\SourceFile"
set "Destfolder=D:\PurgeScriptExecute\DestFile"
set _NoOfDays=30
robocopy /S /MINAGE:%_NoOfDays% "%Sourcefolder%" "%Destfolder%" /E 
echo File copied Successful^>^>%Sourcefolder%>>%Destfolder%
```

This works perfectly but only for files and not the folders inside the source directory .I don't understand why ??

**Note**

```
I don't have to move the files and folders . I need to copy them.
```

Comment: I would assume it is getting confused by the fact that you are using `/S` and `/E`.  Should only be using one or the other. Best practice is to put all the options at the end. `robocopy  "%Sourcefolder%" "%Destfolder%" /E /MINAGE:%_NoOfDays%`

Comment: If that does not help, start with: `robocopy  "%Sourcefolder%" "%Destfolder%" /E /CREATE`

Comment: @Squashman This didn't work !! still getting the same issue

Comment: @Luuk what about %NoOfDays% ??

Comment: @AlokSharma: You can test to see if that is working. I do not know the `Age` of the directory. If you use `/CREATE` it will copy all directories.

Comment: It seems `/MINAGE` does apply and not to folders. The help page says : "Specifies the minimum **file** age (exclude files newer than n days or date)."